# How to refactor: Outer class SLList<T> with inner class assigning <T>. Can the inner class be moved to its own .java file?

Tags: java, list

I'm writing my own singly-linked list class for an assignment. I originally had my Node class in the root directory inside its own java file, but it assigns the generic `T` to *obj*, so it looks like it has to be nested inside `SLList<T>`.

My question (unrelated to the assignment): Is there a way to *extract* the `Node` class from the outer class, or must it be defined inside the outer class because it inherits the  assignment?

```
public class SLList<T> {

    Node head; // Front of the queue
    Node tail; // Back of the queue
    int count; // The number of elements in the queue

    public class Node {
        T obj; // The stored object in this node.
        Node next; // The reference to the next object, null if final element.
    }
...
...
...
```

If I create Node in an outer class, I run into the following error:

```
...
...
    public T remove() {
        // If empty, just return null:
        if (count == 0)
            return null;
        // Set
        T obj = head.obj; // ERROR: Object cannot be converted to type T.
        head = head.next;
        if (--count == 0)
            tail = null;
        return obj;
    }
```

Comment: You can, but then you need to define `Node` with a generic parameter. That is, `class Node<T> { T obj; Node<T> next; }`. Don't forget to provide the declared types of `head` and `tail` with their type arguments, i.e. `Node<T>` head` and `Node<T> tail`.

Comment: Alright, but then I have a problem: See edit.

Comment: Also the variables need to know their type parameter: `Node<T> head;`